# Checking file permissions for a specified user account in Java

Tags: java

I'm running a Java application as a Windows Service and am using another Java application, which is executed by another user, to set a directory used by the Windows Service application.

Is there a way in Java to determine the file permissions of a directory for another user?  In my case, I want to know the file permissions of the Windows Service application while running a separate Java application executed by another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of filesystem support is not available in standard Java, because Java is cross-platform and filesystem security differs greatly across platforms (or may not exist at all).  However, there are plans to add this support to Java 7 (which we have been waiting for years to get!)

If you are only using it on Windows and you know C/C++, you can use a JNI (Java Native Interface) like [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) to tap into the Windows DLLs and get this information.  Otherwise, you can get a trial or a paid version of [JNIWrapper](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack) which works out-of-the-box.  I'm not sure if it provides support for file security, but it does provide other filesystem support - you'll need to review the feature list.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was true after searching around online, but the lack of information regarding this topic leads me to believe that Java just doesn't support this type of operation.  Hopefully Java 7 fixes all.

Comment: Yes, believe me, it's a pain that this isn't supported, and it is a pain for thousands of developers out there!  There has been lots of speculation about what will eventually make it into Java 7 and what won't but it looks pretty certain now that this will go in. See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#7